# Reversing collection List<Object> without allocating ListIterator

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a collection List and i need to reverse order of it. 
Everything works fine with

```
List<Point> myList = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

i can reverse it with

```
Collections.reverse(myList);
```

but this causes to allocate java.util.AbstractList$FullListIterator

i have about 5000 - 10000 paths to reverse in pathfinder and this causes GC to kick in.

How can i reverse this without any neccessary allocation ? I'm using generic pools whenever i can but i'm stuck with this.

Comment: Is a reverse view (not a copy) could be acceptable ? Like [this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse(java.util.List)).

Comment: will this not allocate anything new ?

Comment: There is new allocation. If your list implements RandomAccess, it is a O(1) operation instead of O(n/2) for a classic copy. Since it is a reversed list view, the behaviour is also different: "changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop on the length of the list and swap items at index `i` and `(n-i-1)`. No allocation required.

```
int n = myList.size();
for (int i=n/2; i-->0;) {
    Object o = myList.get(i);
    myList.set(i, myList.get(n-i-1));
    myList.set(n-i-1, o);
}
```

Comment: then the object in 'i' is lost. better use a swap. using a temp variable

Comment: ... or use `Collections.swap()`?

Comment: and also do 'myList.size()' out side the for loop

Comment: @LukasEder Why not. I let you make an an answer with the swap method (I don't like to recall those methods whose use is so rare).

Comment: @Archie.bpgc `myList.size()` is yet called outside the loop. Read again.

Comment: no its not. i mean to say *int i = myList.size()/2...for(int n = 0; n < i; n++){}* is a good practice. like in Manuzor's answer. But he is using size/2 again in the loop. better use that in the 1st line

Comment: @LukasEder I think I got it right (the rounding ensures the middle item is not attained if the size is odd). Just copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, construct your datastructure in the way you don't have to loop again. By this I mean to say.. If you are reading this from a database, use `order by` clause

Comment: +1 I agree. If you get the chance, let the database handle sorting or ordering. As far as I know it usually knows how to handle that stuff more efficiently.

Comment: this is a 2d scene with points ( x,y ) generated in realtime, there are power sources , connectors, and receivers, i'm finding shortest paths using Dijkstra which is reversing from -> to

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int size = myList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
    Point temp = myList.get(i);
    myList.set(i, myList.get(size - i - 1));
    myList.set(size - i - 1, temp);
}
```

All this allocates is one reference to Point so that should be fine in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Run the loop for half the size of list, it will be like swapping these 
`first-with-last
second-with-(last-1)
third-with-(last-2) ...so on...`

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size()/2;i++){           
    Object temp=list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(list.size()-(i+1)));
    list.set(list.size()-(i+1), temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is an ArrayList absolutely necessary?

If reversing is your only important task, you can replace it with a [java linked list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), and get better performance both time-wise and space-wise.